# Distributing scheduled tasks with efficient processor usage

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Suppose 50K Runnables are to be scheduled to execute indefinitely every 30 mins. 
Each Runnable will take 1-5 secs, and perform one Socket operation. 
The TheadPool is of 200 size.

Now How to determine the initial invoking delay of each 50K Runnables with scheduleWithFixedDelay calls (or) how to schedule these Runnables in a processor efficient way.

Is there any standard algorithm for distributing these kind of scheduling.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not throw the `Runnable` instances at the executor and let it work through them as fast as possible? What's the purpose of that initial delay? NB: For that many I/O bound(?) operations, you might be better off using an async execution scheme.

Comment: I'm really curious why would you need 50,000 Runnables!

Comment: What do you mean by "processor efficient way"? As far as I understand, you do not need to calculate delay manually. You just create one ScheduledExecutor with 1 thread in it, and second just simple Executor with 200 threads. First ScheduledExecutor run just one task -- "every 30 minutes put all 50K Runnables into the second Executor queue". This will give you the solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that 10k simultaneous threads, in general, too hard for JVM.

Comment: @Waldheinz I submitted with initial delay 0 secs and found the no. of tasks gets executed in every 10 secs vary too much within 30 mins, ie, some 5 tasks some 400 tasks. I would like to have an uniform number of task per sub-interval. Also, number of sockets failures. Got to try asynchrous scheme for sockets, but where to start?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 50K Runnables which take on up to 5 seconds each that is 250,000 seconds of work.  If you want to run this every 30 * 60 seconds, you need to run this across a minimum of 139 threads.  If you use 200 threads it could take 20 minutes to execute them all.  You may need more threads if you want these tasks to complete in say 5 minutes.

A simple read or write shouldn't take 1-5 seconds. By one Socket operation do you mean a read or a write or do you mean open a socket, send some data and get a reply?  The later can involve a lot of overhead.

While 50K is a lot, I would just have this many scheduled tasks, unless you need tasks to be run on the 30 minute interval as close as possible. If you have 50K independent tasks they will run approximately every 30 minutes but run at different times to each other.  This is unavoidable to some degree as you don't have 50K cores, but how concerned are you about running them as close as possible?

Comment: socket read and write . the interval at which tasks run are very important and got to invoke other objects on any error with socket operations.

Comment: Like I said, it will take up to 20 minutes to execute them all.  What will happen in this case?

Comment: the thing is without socket operations it works fine. But when I use sockets the load increases dramatically(linux).

Comment: Creating a socket is expensive which is why it is usually best to keep a socket open if you can.

Answer (score 0):

distributing scheduling based on your time limit is probably the way to go.

If you have 30 minutes, that's 1800 seconds in which to schedule and complete all 50000 jobs.

So accounting for the time to complete the last round of jobs you have 50000/(1800-5).

That equates to completing about 28(rounded up) jobs a second. So a simple approach could be to just schedule at least 28 jobs every second. That minimizes simultaneous consumption of resources while completing all jobs with in the designated time period. We won't need to worry about the thread pool size for socket operations because if operations complete with in a maximum time of 5 seconds then the maximum number of simultaneous socket operations happening this way will be 140.

Obviously implementing such a schedule would be a simple for loop from 0 to 1794 as the delay time scheduling a set number of jobs, in this case 28. Followed by a delay to round off to the 30 minute mark before starting again.